# Auto update app in azure container apps on docker image push

Tags: azure, azure-container-apps

I have a new app deployed to azure container apps. The image is stored also on azure container registry.

What I would like, when I push a new image to lets say with develop tag, the container app recognizes that and creates a new revision.

How you can do that?

Comment: are you pushing your image manually ? you can use a CICD tool to push then create a new revision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To automatically create new revisions in Azure container apps whenever a new version is available, you can utilize a CICD approach. Thanks @Thomas for suggesting the same. I followed the steps below to achieve this requirement.

First, I **enabled managed identity** in the Container app and assigned the **AcrPull** permission as shown in the screenshot.
[image]

[image]

Next, I created a CI/CD pipeline with two tasks. The first task is **Docker@2**(buildAndPush) and the second task is **AzureContainerApps@1**(creates new revision in Azure container app)

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:

- task: Docker@2
  displayName: Build & Push docker image to ACR
  inputs:
    containerRegistry: 'svc-acr' #using service connection for authenticating to ACR
    repository: 'testimg'
    command: 'buildAndPush'
    Dockerfile: 'Dockerfile'
    tags: |
      develop
      $(Build.BuildId)

- task: AzureContainerApps@1
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'svcv-g'
    acrName: 'containerregistryvjy'
    imageToDeploy: 'containerregistryvjy.azurecr.io/testimg:$(Build.BuildId)'
    containerAppName: 'acavjy01'
    resourceGroup: 'rg-name'
    containerAppEnvironment: 'managedEnvironment-rgname-bfb2'
```

To test the flow, save and run the pipeline and verify the output.

[enter link description here](https://i.imgur.com/UmoqKfI.png)

[image]

I also made a minor change in the code and ran the pipeline to ensure that continuous deployment (CD) is working as expected.

[image]